# Windows 10 Disable RequireSecureNegotiate

Tags: windows-10, smb

Trying to connect to my Uni's network drives where SMB3.0 is not supported. I've read about setting RequireSecureNegotiate to 0 in the registry, however, the key gets deleted straight away. On a Microsoft help article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098) it states that this may be removed in the future. So assuming this registry key method has been disabled (note: the powershell command doesn't work either). Is there an alternative I can try?

Thanks